# Adding USER to Dockerfile results in /bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /home/app/my_script

COPY pyproject.toml /home/app/my_script
COPY poetry.lock /home/app/my_script

RUN groupadd -g 9999 app; \
    useradd -ms /bin/bash -u 9999 -g app app; \
    mkdir /home/app/.ssh; \
    ssh-keyscan github.com >> /home/app/.ssh/known_hosts; \
    chown -R app:app /home/app

USER app # THIS LINE HERE

RUN pip install poetry==1.3.1

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root

COPY src/. /home/app/my_script/

CMD poetry run python script.py
```

The `USER` line changes things in a way I don't understand. We need to do it for security reasons so as to not run as root. Without it everything works perfectly (locally). With it, the result of `docker build...` is

```
[7/8] RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false   && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root: #11 0.432 /bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found
```

Basically, I don't understand how USER changes what packages are accessible in following RUN commands.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: if I add `ENV PATH = "${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin"` I get `/bin/sh: 1: poetry: Permission denied`.

Comment: running with a user flag, `RUN pip install poetry==1.3.1 --user`, results in the same original error.

Comment: If you try logging in to the system as the `app` user, is the `poetry` command available in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Python has two "normal" places packages can be installed.  "System" packages are often installed in somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, but this directory generally requires root access.  "User" packages are typically installed under `$HOME/.local`, which will be writable by "the current user" but not necessarily for other users.

The complication you're running into is when a package declares a [Python entry point](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) (distinct from a Docker entrypoint).  `pip` will install a small wrapper script into a `bin` directory.  If you're root, this can be `/usr/local/bin`, which is on `$PATH`.  But if you're not, the entry point wrappers will wind up somewhere like `$HOME/.local/bin`, which usually isn't on `$PATH`.

In a Docker context, the easiest way to address this is to do all package installation as root.  Having a non-root user to run the container is good practice, but don't switch `USER` until the end of the Dockerfile.  Leave your source code owned by root; it will still be world-readable and your application will still run, but you'll gain an extra measure of safety from not being able to accidentally overwrite your code at runtime.

```bash
RUN useradd -r -U app  # the specific uid doesn't matter

# still as root
RUN pip install poetry==1.3.1

# still as root
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root

COPY src/. ./

# now that the installation is done, switch users
USER app

# run the script -- dependencies should be installed globally
# so the `poetry run` wrapper shouldn't be necessary
CMD ["./script.py"]
```

Comment: "In a Docker context, the easiest way to address this is to do all package installation as root." Is this actually secure?

Comment: To the extent that Python package installations can involve executing `setup.py` scripts, there is non-zero risk here, but it's mitigated some by being inside the container environment – it would be hard for a naughty package to compromise your host or get access to data that's not `COPY`ed into the image.  It depends on your risk profile to be sure but I'd probably consider this "safe enough".